# Force numeric input when viewing website on Android & iOS

Tags: android, ios, html

I need to have an input which will remain `type="text"`, but will open the numeric keyboard on both Android and iOS devices.

This is because the input field will still have characters such as `£` and `,` which will not be possible within a `type="number"` or `type="tel"`.

I've discovered that you can force the numeric keyboard on iOS using `pattern="\d*"`, but this does nothing for Android.

Here is what I have so far:

```
<input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d*" value="£2,000,000" />
```

http://jsbin.com/nelodixeza/edit?html,output

Comment: If you only want to disable validation, you can use "novalidate" attribute.

Comment: @pcagica its nothing to do with validation, I just need the numeric keyboard to open on a ```type=text``` input. Please read the question...

Comment: So I did not understand the question sorry, you why do you wan't a type text then? You can force the numeric keyboard with pattern's as you said.

Comment: I use this pattern="[0-9]*" instead of "\d*", works on both ios and android

Comment: Because it is a field for entering money with symbols such as ```£``` and ```,``` which cannot be entered into a ```type=number``` or ```type=tel``` input

Comment: Also pattern="[0-9]*" does not open the numeric keyboard on Android

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/103975/discussion-between-pcagica-and-michael-wilson).

Comment: try to add a pattern of [0-9] like so <input type="text" inputmode="numeric" pattern="\d*" value="£2,000,000" />

Comment: @Hassan [0-9] doesn't work on Android http://jsbin.com/qifoyosoqa/edit?html,output

Comment: Just for fun: put a clicklistener on it and have a hidden numeric text field with a textwatcher on it which gets the focus on the click, receives the numeric input and then append the numeric input to a string followed by a settext on the actual textfield on display. ANDROOOOOID!

Answer (score 6):

**Edit** *(In case the comments are cleaned up) this answer was written before the question specified it was for mobile web vs mobile apps. However, this answer will help those looking for a solution when using a WebView on Android.*

On Android the WebView used for displaying the page can override onCreateInputConnection. With this method you can alter the imeOptions, although you are still limited to the same numeric types. Alternatively you could work on [creating your own ime type](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/text/creating-input-method.html).

An example:

```
@Override
public InputConnection onCreateInputConnection(EditorInfo outAttrs) {
    InputConnection inputConnection = super.onCreateInputConnection(outAttrs);
    outAttrs.inputType = outAttrs.inputType | InputType.TYPE_NUMBER_VARIATION_NORMAL;
    return inputConnection;
}
```

However, while I'm sure the above will solve many peoples problems, I think you need something a little more complex. My suggestion is that whatever keyboard type you use, you use java to validate and format your input, which takes a couple of steps:

**Setup a javascript interface**

```
webView.addJavascriptInterface(new ValidationInterface(), "appValidator");
```

**Create the interface class**

```
public class ValidationInterface {

    //This method would only tell you if a char is invalid
    @JavascriptInterface
    public boolean isValid(String text){
        int len = text.length();
        //replace everything thats NOT 0-9, $, £, comma or dot
        text = text.replaceAll("[^0-9$£,\.", "");
        //Its valid if the length didnt change (because nothing needs removing)
        return text.length() == len;
    }

    //This method would strip out invalid text as you go
    @JavascriptInterface
    public String getValid(String text){
        //replace everything thats NOT 0-9, $, £, comma or dot
        return text.replaceAll("[^0-9$£,\.", "");
    }

}
```

**Call the validation when the text changes**

```
function validate(value) {
    //ive not written js in a long time, you'll definitely need to tweak this
    //EITHER do this
    var valid = appValidator.isValid(value);
    if (valid) {
        //DO SOEMTHING
    } ...

    //OR try this
    var validText = appValidator.getValid(value);
    $('#theField').value(validText); //really not sure this is valid
}

//also just be aware you might need to use keyUp or somethign other than change
//if you are replacing the text as you type, using getValid method
<input id="theField" type="text" onChange="validate(this.value)" ... />
```

Comment: Is there anyway of getting a live example of this? I have never used Andriod's WebView so I don't know where to start. This is needed on a website, is this meant to be for an app?

Comment: Yes, this would be for a webview in an android app (because I thought you tagged the platforms and didnt mention website - I've just realised you didnt add those tags)

Comment: I've awarded the bounty to this answer, as its the only one which works (does not fit my current needs though, i.e it needs to work on a normal website).

Answer (score 2):

I was working on something similar

have a look at my example : https://jsfiddle.net/pj2uwmtL/6/

```
$("input.numbers").keypress(function(event) {
  return /\d/.test(String.fromCharCode(event.keyCode));
});
```

Comment: Just spotted some odd behaviour on the fiddle I send you (Android only). If you start typing numbers it won't allow you to type any letters but if initially you type a letter it will not work. Lets see how we could get around this.

Comment: I just found this that I think is pretty much what you are after: http://www.decorplanit.com/plugin/

Comment: First of all, what version of android are you testing on?

Comment: KitKat I think, 4.4.2

Comment: Sorry, couldn't find a way to switch between numeric and symbols (currency symbols) keyboard. I thought on a different way of achieving what you wanted but not sure you'll like it. https://jsfiddle.net/pj2uwmtL/6/

Answer (score 1):

I use:

```
<input type="text" pattern="\d*" />
```

Nothing else is necessary.

Works very well on iPhone particularly with the new keyboard types. Works with the default and Swiftkey.

In addition this works on all Android devices.

**Update:**

Give this a shot:

```
<input type="text" step="0.01" pattern="[0-9]*">

<input type="text" min="0" max="100" pattern="[0-9]*">

Or

<input type="text" pattern="\-?\d+(\.\d{0,})?">
```

Comment: This is the pattern I'm already using (see question) and ```pattern="\d*"``` does not work on Android

Comment: Will do, but real quick. Why does it *have* to be `"text"`?

Comment: It needs to be text to allow characters such as ```£``` and ```,``` as this is for a "money" input.

Comment: I just tested your update, none of them work on Android: https://jsfiddle.net/3k4v38e6/

Comment: There is no "money" keyboard though. I would recommend sticking with text

Comment: when i say "money" input, i'm meaning the reason there is a symbol and commas is because it is an input for entering "money".

Comment: despite what the answerer says, this doesn't work on Android